# Javascript fullscreen api

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone please explain how the following code works.

Element refers to the video while fullscreen is a link on the page.

I am having trouble understanding the if statements

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
var fullscreen = document.getElementById('fullscreen');

fullscreen.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (element.requstFullscreen) {
        element.requstFullscreen();
    } else if (element.webkitrequestFullscreen) {
        element.webkitrequestFullscreen();
    };
});
```

Comment: `if (element.requstFullscreen) {` tests if `element.requstFullscreen` exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
```

If the element object contains something called `requestFullscreen`, call it (there was a typo which I fixed). This is the standard way to go full-screen via Javascript.

```
} else if (element.webkitrequestFullscreen) { 
    element.webkitrequestFullscreen();
}
```

If it does not, but contains something called `webkitrequestFullscreen`, call that. This is how you do it in older Chrome/Safari.

And by the way, a more reliable way to check existence of functions is `typeof`:

```
if (typeof element.requestFullscreen == "function") {
```

Comment: if element has the method requestFullscreen, then call it?

Comment: Yes, but the plain `if` just checks if `requestFullscreen` _exists_; it could be, for example, just a string (no idea why, but still). I explained another better method using `typeof` in my post.

Answer (score 0):

in full screen, when you click:

if `element` has attribute `requestFullscreen`, then `requestFullscreen()` will be called,
otherwise, `webkitrequestFullscreen()` will be called.

Thats the best I can say without seeing requestFullscreen() and webkitrequestfullscreen().

Comment: I think what you mean is "property" not "attribute".